# Como enviar objetos entre Intents en andriod studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, poo, android-intent

Hola estoy intentando comunicar 2 controladoras:

Nota: al momento de enviar `putExtra("ID", entero, string, ... objeto simple)` funciona perfectamente.

pero estoy intentando enviar esta controladora:

https://github.com/felipedelosh/LifeRegisterAPP/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/liferegisterdiary/Controller.java

A esta otra controladora:

https://github.com/felipedelosh/LifeRegisterAPP/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/liferegisterdiary/Register.java

```
        //User is register?
        if(!controller.userIsRegister()){
            Intent launchResgisterView = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class);
            //Send a main controller <No funciona>
            launchResgisterView.putExtra("mainController", controller);


            startActivity(launchResgisterView);
        }
```

Alguien podria ayudarme a enviar esa controladora?

Comment: Y no puedes directamente instanciar un objeto nuevo allí directamente en vez de mandárselo?

Comment: No es una buena practica de programación instanciar varias veces el mismo objeto, ya que necesitaria instanciarlo en los 10 controladores que voy a crear. además el controlador crea una base de datos... y si lo vuelvo a instanciar implica que 10 veces va a intertar crear una base de datos.

Comment: Excepto que hagas un Singleton. No estoy seguro de cómo de correcto es usar el patrón singleton en Android, seguro que alguien como elenasys o algún otro conocedor de Android pueden echarte una mano mejor en eso :) Por cierto, si vas a utilizarlo en muchos sitios, yo tampoco me fiaría de andar pasándolo, que al final se te quedará en memoria una activity o fragment porque tienen un servicio que el recolector de basura no puede borrar porque está en uso en otro activity/fragment. Buscaría la manera de tener los servicios siempre disponibles ya sea con Singletons o alguna clase estática tal vez

Answer (score 0):

Para poder enviar objetos entre clases por medio de un `Intent`, lo primero que debes asegurar es que clase objeto implemente la clase `Serializable`:

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable  {
```

y de esta forma puedes enviar sin problema el objeto usando un `Intent`:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class);
 intent.putExtra("mainController", controller);
 startActivity(intent);
```